# bottom align content in divs that based on percentages

Tags: html, css

I have a set of `div`s whose dimensions are set by percentage:

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="x20">content 1</div>
    <div class="x4">gutter</div>
    <div class="x20"> content 2 </div>
    <div class="x4">gutter</div>
    <div class="x20"> content 3 </div>
    <div class="x4">gutter</div>
    <div class="x20"> content 4 </div>
    <div class="x4">gutter</div>
</div>



.parent {
   position: absolute;
   left: 50%;
   top: 50%;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
   -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
 }
 .x20 {
   height: 20%;
   border: 2px solid #f0f;
   vertical-align: text-bottom text-align: center;
   position: relative
 }

 .x4 {
   height: 4%;
   border: 2px solid #ccc;
 }
```

How can I get the "content" to be bottom aligned?

Comment: You could put those texts within paragraph tags `<p>content 1</p>` and define `margin-bottom: 5%;` or whatever value seems to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try adding like

```
.x20 p {
 position:absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
}
```

and then including

```
<p> content 1</p>
```

that works for me..

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qObBKQ

Answer (score 0):

Flexbox method can solve this with two lines of code.

`display: flex` and `align-items: flex-end` on the content element.

```css
.parent {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
.x20 {
  height: 20%;
  border: 2px solid #f0f;
  vertical-align: text-bottom text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  display: flex; /* Add to initiate the flex box layout */
  align-items: flex-end; /* Add to align the content to cross-axis end */
}
.x4 {
  height: 4%;
  border: 2px solid #ccc;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="x20">content 1</div>
  <div class="x4">gutter</div>
  <div class="x20">content 2</div>
  <div class="x4">gutter</div>
  <div class="x20">content 3</div>
  <div class="x4">gutter</div>
  <div class="x20">content 4</div>
  <div class="x4">gutter</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following :

**HTML**

```
<div class="x20"> 
    <div class="x10"> content 1</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.x20 {
   height: 20%;
   border: 2px solid #f0f;
   position: relative
 }

.x10 {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 50%; 
}
```

Add another `div` inside your content container and position that `absolute` should solve your problem.

See the following JSFIDDLE - [LINK](https://jsfiddle.net/3nctadb8/)

Answer (score 0):

try:

```css
.x20 {
      height: 20%;
      border: 2px solid #f0f;
      vertical-align: bottom;
      text-align: center;
      display: inline-block ;
    }
```

```css
.x4 {
   height: 4%;
   border: 2px solid #ccc;
   display: inline-block ;
   vertical-align: bottom ;
 }
```